# Typescript: valueof array in nested template object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to type de values of an array in a template object.
Currently I have achieved my goal using objects like so :

```
// defining the model type
interface RouteModel {
    route: string
    params?: Record<string, string>
}

interface RoutesModel {
    [routeName: string]: RouteModel
}

// value constructor
function makeRoutes<T extends RoutesModel>(input: T) {
  return input
}

// type safe creation for routes
const routes = makeRoutes({
  potato: {
    route: '/potato/:potatoId/rate',
    params: { potatoId: '' },
  },
  grapes: {
    route: 'grapes',
  },
  banana: {
    route: 'bag/:bagId/:bananaId',
    params: { bagId: '', bananaId: '' },
  },
})

const useTypedHistory = <T extends RoutesModel>() => {
  const navigate = <K extends keyof T>(route: K, params: Record<keyof T[K]['params'], string>) => {

  }

  return { navigate }
}

const Component = () => {
  const { navigate } = useTypedHistory<typeof routes>()
  navigate('banana', { bagId: '123', bananaId: '567' })
                     ʌ --- type safety works here, it requires the right object depending on the first param

  return null
}

export default useTypedHistory
```

My problem is that at the beginning, I declare my params as an object with the correct keys but empty string to make it work.

I would like to an array of strings instead, so it would look like this:

```
 // defining the model type
interface RouteModel {
    route: string
    params?: string[]
}

interface RoutesModel {
    [routeName: string]: RouteModel
}

// value constructor
function makeRoutes<T extends RoutesModel>(input: T) {
  return input
}

// type safe creation for routes
const routes = makeRoutes({
  potato: {
    route: '/potato/:potatoId/rate',
    params: ['potatoId'],
  },
  grapes: {
    route: 'grapes',
  },
  banana: {
    route: 'bag/:bagId/:bananaId',
    params: ['bagId', 'bananaId'],
  },
})

const useTypedHistory = <T extends RoutesModel>() => {
  const navigate = <K extends keyof T>(route: K, params: Record<(valueof T[K]['params']), string>) => {
                                                               ʌ --- does not work
  }

  return { navigate }
}
```

But that doesn't work at all. From what I've seen, `valueof` would allow me to infer the values, but I can't seem to make it work.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: What do you expect/want valueof T[K]['params'] to return? You have a multistring array and try to to fit it into a string.

Comment: Do you have documentation for a `valueof` keyword? Can't find it ... From a tuple you can access the union type with `T[K]['params'][number]`, however I'm not sure if a tuple type gets inferred here or a `string[]`. `as const` at various places might help.